# Is there a way to disable the auto collapse on react-bootstrap's accordion

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

is there a way to disable the auto collapse on the react-bootstrap accordion
Ex: if the user wants to open two content at once, then he can

```
                    <Accordion>
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Header>
                                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                                    Click me!
                                </Accordion.Toggle>
                            </Card.Header>
                            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                                <h1>Hello! I'm the body</h1>
                            </Accordion.Collapse>
                        </Card>
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Header>
                                <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                                    Click me!
                                </Accordion.Toggle>
                            </Card.Header>
                            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                                <h1>Hello! I'm another body</h1>
                            </Accordion.Collapse>
                        </Card>
                    </Accordion>
```

Comment: are you asking if there's a way to have multiple panes in an accordion open at once?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Only one item can be collapsed in one Accordion Component and that should be with different eventKey for each Accordion.Toggle and Accordion.Collapse like this:

```
<Accordion>
    <Card>
        <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                Click me!
            </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <h1>Hello! I'm the body</h1>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
    <Card>
        <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="1">
                Click me!
            </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
            <h1>Hello! I'm another body</h1>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
</Accordion>
```

If you want to have different items that can be opened separately without any effect on each other, you can use two different Accordion Components like this:

```
            <Accordion>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                            Click me!
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                        <h1>Hello! I'm the body</h1>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
            </Accordion>
            <Accordion>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="1">
                            Click me!
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                        <h1>Hello! I'm another body</h1>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
            </Accordion>
```